# Makefile : delimit a shell variable ($$var)

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a shell variable in a for loop and I would like to indicate the end of the name of this variable:

```
$(DEBUG)for extblock in $(EXT_BLOCKS_LIST); \
    do cat syn/ext_$$extblock_syn.tcl >> syn/$(SYN_TCL_SCRIPT); \
done;
```

My variable is only $$extblock but make takes $$extblock_syn as variable.

I don't achieve to put () correctly. Is there another character to indicate the end of a variable name?

Comment: You might be able to refactor this into a single `cat` command without a loop, depending on what exactly you have in `EXT_BLOCKS_LIST`. Maybe `cat $(patsubst %,syn/ext_%_syn.tcl,$(EXT_BLOCKS_LIST)) > syn/$(SYN_TCL_SCRIPT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
do cat syn/ext_$${extblock}_syn.tcl >> syn/$(SYN_TCL_SCRIPT);\
```

Braces can be used as delimiters.  Also see the [bash manual on shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).